# Validate Data that is being read from an Excel File with EP Plus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

Hi I have been following the example code in [Sample 11 on the EP Plus website](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleApp/Sample11.cs). I have added validation to the file I am creating but I am unsure how to check that the validations are correct. My code so far is as follows

```
foreach (var dataValidation in codes.DataValidations)
{
    dataValidation.Validate();
}
```

but I am unsure exactly what is happening here. From looking at the source code for Validate() I know that an Exception will be thrown. Can anyone explain what this is doing?

What I want to achieve is check that each cell that I am reading data from meets the validation requirements before I upload the data to my database. Is this a reliable way of validating the data or should I check the data in an other way for example against my view model.

Has anyone done this before and do they know what happens if the validation is removed from the excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I added validation to the worksheet as follows

```
        var paretnCodeValidation = codeSheet.DataValidations.AddTextLengthValidation("B:B");
        paretnCodeValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        paretnCodeValidation.ErrorStyle = ExcelDataValidationWarningStyle.stop;
        paretnCodeValidation.ErrorTitle = "An invalid value was entered";
        paretnCodeValidation.Error = "Parent must be between 1 and 50 digits in length";
        paretnCodeValidation.Formula.Value = 1;
        paretnCodeValidation.Formula2.Value = 50;
```

And when the excel file was being uploaded back to the application I check the values using the View Model